# fullpage js scrollOverflow is not working when scrollBar is set to false

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gsap, elementor, fullpage.js

I have a section which has some content more that the viewport height.
The fullpage.js option scrollOverflow is set to true but always the output is force me to use scrollBar to false then the section became scrollable.
But if I set scrollBar to true then the section is not scrolling anymore.
I need to keep the scrollBar to true for some jquery wheel animation.

This is the code I'm using:

`

```
var myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
        licenseKey: '67582BFF-B4A142AC-ABCE62BE-45C58F1F',
        sectionSelector: '.section',
        scrollBar: true,
//      fitToSection: false,
        scrollingSpeed: 1300,
        bigSectionsDestination: top,
        css3: true,
        slideSelector: '.slide',
//         normalScrollElements: '.normal_scroll',
        scrollOverflow: true,
        scrollOverflowMacStyle: true,
        onScrollOverflow: function(section, slide, position, direction){
            var params = {
                section: section,
                slide: slide,
                position: position,
                direction: direction
            };

            //console.log("--- onScrollOverflow ---");
            //console.log(params);
        },
        //controlArrows: false,
        loopHorizontal: false,
        responsiveWidth: 1025,
```

`

Comment: You mean, when scrollBar is set to true?
Yeah, that's expected. You should see a warning on your JS console telling you those both options can't be used together.

Comment: no, there was no error in console like the logs you have mentioned. @Alvaro
Then what should I do?
I need the scorlling animation for which the scrollbar needs to be true and the scrollable section must scroll to.

I have used setAllowScrolling false when the scrollable section is active onLeave and tried to scroll the section after that and calculating the end the of the scrollable section to reactive the setAllowScrolling to true on mouse wheel detection. But not working properly.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Use `scrollBar: false` and that should fix the issue.
scrollBar: true is not compatible with scrollOverflow.

Comment: Related with: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/3403